# What's the best way to release resources after java.util.Timer?

Tags: java, concurrency, timertask, try-with-resources

I have an AutoCloseable whose close() method is being called prematurely. The AutoCloseable is ProcessQueues below. I don't want the close() method to be called when it is currently being called. I'm considering the removal of "implements AutoCloseable" to accomplish that. But then how do I know when to call ProcessQueues.close()?

```
 public class ProcessQueues implements AutoCloseable {
    private ArrayList<MessageQueue> queueObjects    = new ArrayList<MessageQueue>();

    public ProcessQueues() {
        queueObjects.add(new FFE_DPVALID_TO_SSP_EXCEPTION());
        queueObjects.add(new FFE_DPVALID_TO_SSP_ESBEXCEPTION());
        ...
    }
    
    private void scheduleProcessRuns() {
        try {
            for (MessageQueue obj : queueObjects) {
                monitorTimer.schedule(obj, new Date(), 1); // NOT THE ACTUAL ARGUMENTS
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
           // NOT THE ACTUAL EXCEPTION HANDLER
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
      try (ProcessQueues pq = new ProcessQueues()) {
        pq.scheduleProcessRuns();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // NOT THE ACTUAL EXCEPTION HANDLER
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
      for (MessageQueue queue : queueObjects) {
        queue.close();
      }
    }
}
```

I want ProcessQueues.close() to be called, but not until the task execution threads of all Timer objects terminate. As written, ProcessQueues.close() will be called as soon as the tasks are *scheduled*. I can easily solve that by removing "implements AutoCloseable" from the ProcessQueues class (and removing the @Override annotation). But then I have to call ProcessQueues.close() myself. How do I know when the task execution threads of all Timer objects have terminated? That's when I want to call ProcessQueues.close().

Note that MessageQueue isn't instantiated in the resource specification header of a try-with-resources block, so although MessageQueue also implements AutoCloseable, the feature isn't utilized here. I'm explicitly calling MessageQueue.close(). It is in MessageQueue.close() that I release resources. Releasing those resources prematurely causes the task execution threads to fail to complete their tasks.

I'm considering an explicit call to ProcessQueues.close() after rewriting the code to prevent automatic resource deallocation, but again I don't know how to discover the right time for that explicit call.

I considered overriding ProcessQueues.finalize(), but "Java: How to Program", Eleventh Edition advises against that. "You should never use method finalize, because it can cause many problems and there's uncertainty as to whether it will ever get called before a program terminates... Now it's considered better practice for any class that uses system resources... to provide a method that programmers can call to release resources when they're no longer needed in a program." I have such a method. It's ProcessQueues.close(). But when should I call it?

Comment: `close` will be called when the `try-catch` exits, it's probably not the best choice

Comment: Why are you not using the Executors framework that supplanted `Timer` class years ago?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
      }` do not silently swallow exceptions

Comment: Do you understand that `monitorTimer.schedule(obj, new Date(), 1)` schedules a task to run repeatedly once per millisecond? Why so fast, every millisecond? And if scheduling to repeat endlessly, what does it mean for your `Timer` to "have terminated"? A repeating task will continue repeating indefinitely. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I agree, @MadProgrammer.

Comment: @Scary, it's not real code. I removed the exception handlers for this post so that no one would be distracted by them. They have nothing to do with the problem I describe.

Comment: @BasilBorque, like I said, those are not the real arguments to the schedule method. I'm just showing you which overload I'm calling. I know that the task is scheduled to run repeatedly and endlessly. But nothing is truly endless. The threads will eventually cease to execute. That's when the MessageQueue objects will no longer be needed and that's when I want MessageQueue.close() called.

Comment: @BasilBorque, it's not new code. It's not my code. Timer was selected by a predecessor. I accept the blame for AutoCloseable, which I intend to fix. Consideration of the Executors framework will be given at a future date (or now if necessary). My focus right now is on calling MessageQueue.close() at the appropriate time.

Comment: Please vote to reopen this question. It was sufficiently detailed and clear when first asked. Upon discovering it to have been closed, I added verbosity.  Please do not focus on the dummy arguments I provided for Timer.schedule(). They have nothing to do with the question that was asked. Nor should you focus on exception handlers I deliberately emptied for the sake of this discussion. I have scheduled tasks to run repeatedly. How do I determine that they have stopped running so that I can perform termination housekeeping? If you think the Executors framework answers my question, explain why.

Comment: When composing `Closeable`s and closing multiple resources inside one `close()` method, you should add a try-catch inside the loop so that you don't leave the other resources open if one fails to close. Remember the first exception occured, add all subsequent via `.addSuppressed`. Throw the first exception (with all subsequent added via `addSuppressed`) after closing all resources if one occured.

Answer (score 2):

You have conflicting lifecycle issues here.

You have `Timer` whose lifecycle is 100% in your control. You start it, you stop it, and that's it. But you have no direct introspection in to the status of the threads being managed by the Timer. So, you can't ask it if it has anything currently running, for example.

Then you have your `MessageQueue`, which is invoked by the `Timer`. This is the lifecycle you're interested in. You want to wait for all of the `MessageQueues` to be "done", for assorted values of done. But, since the queue are constantly being rescheduled (given the `Timer.schedule` method that you're using), they're NEVER "done". They process their contents and go off and run again.

So, how is anyone to know when "done" means "done"?

Is it up to the `MessageQueue`? Or is it up to the `ProcessQueues`? Who's in command here?

Notice, nothing ever cancels the `Timer`. It's just runs on and on and on.

So, how can one know when `MessageQueue` can be closed?

If `MessageQueue` is the real driver here, then you should add lifecycle methods to the `MessageQueue` that `ProcessQueues` can monitor to know when to shut things down. For example, you could create a `CountDownLatch` set for however many `MessageQueues` are in your list, and then subscribe to a new lifecycle method on the `MessageQueue` that it calls when it's finished. The callback method can then decrement the `CountDownLatch`, and the `ProcessQueues.close` method simply waits on the latch to countdown before closing everything.

```
public class ProcessQueues implements AutoCloseable, MessageQueueListener {

    private ArrayList<MessageQueue> queueObjects = new ArrayList<MessageQueue>();
    CountDownLatch latch;

    public ProcessQueues() {
        queueObjects.add(new FFE_DPVALID_TO_SSP_EXCEPTION());
        queueObjects.add(new FFE_DPVALID_TO_SSP_ESBEXCEPTION());
        ... 
        queueObjects.forEach((mq) -> {
            mq.setListener(this);
        });
        latch = new CountDownLatch(queueObjects.size());
    }

    private void scheduleProcessRuns() {
        try {
            for (MessageQueue obj : queueObjects) {
                monitorTimer.schedule(obj, new Date(), 1); // NOT THE ACTUAL ARGUMENTS
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // NOT THE ACTUAL EXCEPTION HANDLER
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ProcessQueues pq = new ProcessQueues()) {
            pq.scheduleProcessRuns();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // NOT THE ACTUAL EXCEPTION HANDLER
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        latch.await();
        for (MessageQueue queue : queueObjects) {
            queue.close();
        }
        monitorTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void messageQueueDone() {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}

public interface MessageQueueListener {    
    public void messageQueueDone();
}

public class MessageQueue extends TimerTask {
    MessageQueueListener listener;
    
    public void setListener(MessageQueueListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    
    private boolean isMessageQueueReallyDone {
        ...
    }
    public void run() {
        ...
        if (isMessageQueueReallyDone() && listener != null) {
            listener.messageQueueDone();
        }
    }
}
```

Mind, this means that your try-with-resource block will block waiting on all of the `MessageQueues`, if that's what you want, then you're good to go.

It also crassly assumes that your `MessageQueue.run()` knows when to shut down, which goes back to that "who's in control here" thing.

Comment: "If MessageQueue is the real driver here, then" your CountDownLatch example is excellent, but MessageQueue isn't the real driver. ProcessQueues wants to be the driver, but it lost control when it delegated to Timer.

Comment: A MessageQueue doesn't know when it's done. It doesn't even know that a Timer caused it to run repeatedly, but ProcessQueues knows about the endlessness.

Comment: @AlanFeldstein MessageQueues can know when they're idle (i.e. "not running"). ProcessQueues can cancel the Timer, and then tell the MessageQueues that they're done, and then wait on their "I'm done" latches. When the ProcessQueues tells them they're done, if they're idle, they can set their latch immediately. Otherwise, it sets a flag (AtomicBoolean) that the run method looks at, and when it's about to exit, it can set the done latch, "knowing" it won't be called again by the Timer. There will be some synchronization fun to deal with, but that's normal.

Answer (score 0):

I could terminate the `Timer`, but having it run perpetually is intentional. The question is in consideration of what happens when something else terminates the `Timer` and the `MessageQueue` objects are no longer needed. It is at that point that I would like to call `ProcessQueues.close()`.

If I were to use the Executor framework, rather than `Timer`, then I could use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`

`TimerTask` is a `Runnable`, and `MessageQueue` is already a `TimerTask`, so `MessageQueue` need not change.

'ExecutorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)' would effectively wait forever for termination.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {   
  try (ProcessQueues pq = new ProcessQueues()) {
    pq.scheduleProcessRuns();

    // Don't take this literally.
    ExecutorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

  } catch (Exception e) {
     // NOT THE ACTUAL EXCEPTION HANDLER
  }
}
```

Of course, `awaitTermination` isn't a static method, so I'll have to have an ExecutorService, but you get the idea.

After termination, the `AutoCloseable` feature is leveraged and `ProcessQueues.close()` is implicitly called.

All that remains is to start the threads for perpetually repeated calls to each `TimerTask`, using the Executor framework. The answer to that question is `ScheduledExecutorService`.

I think this will work.